# Shopware 6 How can I use the configured primary colour of the theme in scss?

Tags: shopware6

In the theme settings in the administration I am able to set the primary and secondary colours. **How can I use these colours in the theme scss?** I already had a look into the documentation but could only find [how to add config values as scss](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-scss-variables) but not which already exist and what they are called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to figure out what the variables are called:

1. Look for the default values of the variables in the scss. The default values are defined in [`vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/src/scss/skin/shopware/abstract/variables/_theme.scss`](https://github.com/shopware/storefront/blob/trunk/Resources/app/storefront/src/scss/skin/shopware/abstract/variables/_theme.scss) which lists the variables for the values that can be configured in the administration.
2. The fields that may be configured are defined in the [theme.json](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/theme-configuration#config-fields). For the default theme this is located in [`vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/theme.json`](https://github.com/shopware/storefront/blob/trunk/Resources/theme.json). Look for the keys in [`config.fields`](https://github.com/shopware/storefront/blob/a2ec6b3c1bf2808a6a29386d0a544a56a15ada89/Resources/theme.json#L73).

So for the primary and secondary colours the variable names are [`$sw-color-brand-primary`](https://github.com/shopware/storefront/blob/a2ec6b3c1bf2808a6a29386d0a544a56a15ada89/Resources/theme.json#L74) and [`$sw-color-brand-secondary`](https://github.com/shopware/storefront/blob/a2ec6b3c1bf2808a6a29386d0a544a56a15ada89/Resources/theme.json#L85).